# Cuda cudaMemcpy "invalid argument"

Tags: c, cuda

Trying to debug a larger application I'm having an issue where I can't seem to be able to copy values from the host to the device. I provide below a minimal example which *I think* should copy the `6` to the device and then back.

```
#include <stdio.h>
__device__ float a_d;

main(){
    float a = 6.0;
    float b;
    puts(cudaGetErrorString(cudaMemcpy(&a_d,&a,sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)));
    puts(cudaGetErrorString(cudaMemcpy(&b,&a_d,sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)));
    printf("%e",b);
}
```

I get the following output with CUDA 5.5 on 64-bit Linux.

```
$ nvcc test.cu -run
invalid argument
invalid argument
0.000000e+00
```

whereas I'd expect `cudaSuccess` and `6.000000e+00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `cudaMemcpy` directly with `__device__` variables.  The [correct API to use](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-variable-qualifier) is `cudaMemcpyTo/FromSymbol`.

The following should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
__device__ float a_d;

main(){
    float a = 6.0;
    float b;
    puts(cudaGetErrorString(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(a_d,&a,sizeof(float)));
    puts(cudaGetErrorString(cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&b,a_d,sizeof(float)));
    printf("%e",b);
}
```

It's not clear why you'd expect `0.000000e+00`.  Based on your code I would expect `6.000000e+00`, or something like that.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I'd actually tried using that but had different problems because of the nonsense type given [in nvidia's docs](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gf268fa2004636b6926fdcd3189152a14.html#gf268fa2004636b6926fdcd3189152a14).

Comment: that's a link to very old docs (CUDA 4.1 circa 2010).  Current docs are [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#)